# Having difficulties creating a custom command in TF2

Tags: team-fortress-2, cheats

So, in TF2 I like to play on cheat-enabled servers sometimes and I've been trying to create a command that would allow me to pick up an object and "wear" it on my head like a hat, for example a tiny dispencer that I've made with a different command, but problem is I can't seem to get it to work right...

So far what I currently have is:

> alias wearit "ent_fire !picker setparent !player;ent_fire !picker setparentattachment partyhat"

When I use this while aiming at the object I want, such as my tiny dispencer, it does indeed teleport it on top of my head like it should, but the object becomes completely invisible, and I cannot move without using Noclip because the game think's I'm stuck inside the object. (I don't want to use Noclip if there is in fact another way.)

As far as finding a way to solve this, I've been struggling to find any relevant info pre-existing online such as in other people's questions and Valve's official website for these things, and my results have been very limited...

So far the only terms I've found that look like they might work on paper are:

> ent_fire !picker disablecollision 1

and

> ent_fire !picker SetSolidToPlayer 0

Both of those tags should in theory make the object clip right through me and allow me to move without being stuck inside it, but when I add them to my command and try it in practice, the result is the same as without them.

So I've come to you all for help. Can anyone help me find a way to get this working without Noclip?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, what you're doing *should* work (except possibly the movement issue?).

However, here's why it doesn't:

In 2010 or so, certain servers started selling the ability to use any hat in the game to their player base.  Valve noticed and their employees (likely Fletcher Dunn) asked that server owners not do this on the server mailing list and was ignored.

So, Valve simply patched the game to make things you attach to players be invisible except for a few entity types... and those entity types (`tf_weapon_*`/`tf_wearable`) will force the server to do a lookup to see if players own the corresponding items and turn them invisible if they don't.

Comment: Hmm, well that solves the mystery of the invisible dispencer hat, but I still need help with the movement thing... Any ideas?